# Encontrar elemento para remover via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma rotina no JS que é a seguinte:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.remover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.info').html("<p>Escolha ao lado</p>").parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val();
});
```

Gostaria que, ao clicar no .remover, procurasse a div .info mais próxima, substituisse seu conteúdo pelo acima, e também limpasse o valor de dois input hiddens que constam no parent de .info...

Mas não deu. Não retornou nenhum erro de sintaxe, mas não executou a função.

**Estrutura do HTML (Print do Debugger, já que os elementos são adicionados dinamicamente):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso proceder?

Comment: Adiciona o html á pergunta para que seja fácil reproduzir o problema e  dar uma resposta a funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está quase correto, faltou apenas acrescentar duas aspas dentro de `.val()` para limpar os `inputs` (vou deixar os `inputs` visíveis no *sandbox* para ver o efeito):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.remover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.info').html("<p>Escolha ao lado</p>").parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val('');
});
```

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a.remover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.info').html("<p>Escolha ao lado</p>").parent().find('input[type=text]').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carrinhoPacoteSigame">
    <div class="info">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="remover">Remover Item</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <input type="text" name="hdProduto03" value="19" />
        <input type="text" name="hdValor03" value="30" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Esqueci das malditas.